# Deriving a class from MFC CCmdTarget ON_COMMAND

Tags: c++, mfc, command, handler

I have derived a class from CCmdTarget as I want to use this class to call methods elsewhere when ribbon buttons are clicked. So using ON_COMMAND and ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI, the methods are in non-MFC classes so kindof using this as a bridge as the code is non gui/view specific. I have used the class wizard to generate the class and in the app InitInstance i create the instance of the class. The class is created but I dont get the command handler messages, they are seen in other MFC classes just not in this one I have derived directly from CCmdTarget. I have also overridden OnCmdMsg in the derived class and this never gets called. Am I missing something here ? seems like the class is not registered to receive command handler messages ?

header

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

namespace NM
{
    class ISelectedObjects;
}

class CGuiBridge : 
    public CCmdTarget
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CGuiBridge)

public:
    CGuiBridge();
    virtual ~CGuiBridge();


#ifdef _DEBUG
    virtual void AssertValid() const;
#ifndef _WIN32_WCE
    virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
#endif
#endif

private:
    ::std::unique_ptr<NM::ISelectedObjects> _pSelectedObjects;

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    //virtual BOOL OnCmdMsg(UINT nID, int nCode, void* pExtra, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO* pHandlerInfo);
    afx_msg void OnSelectedClear();
    afx_msg void OnUpdateSelectedClear(CCmdUI *pCmdUI);
};
```

cpp

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CGuiBridge, CCmdTarget)

extern ::NM::Registry::IServiceRegistry* reg;

CGuiBridge::CGuiBridge()
{   
    _pSelectedObjects.reset(reinterpret_cast<NM::ISelectedObjects*>(reg->GetClientInterface(L"SELECTEDOBJECTS")));

    if (!_pSelectedObjects)
        throw ::std::runtime_error("Selected Objects Service Not Available, Cannot Continue.");
}

CGuiBridge::~CGuiBridge()
{
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGuiBridge, CCmdTarget)
    ON_COMMAND(IDC_SELECTED_CLEAR, &CGuiBridge::OnSelectedClear)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(IDC_SELECTED_CLEAR, &CGuiBridge::OnUpdateSelectedClear)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()




// CGuiBridge message handlers


//BOOL CGuiBridge::OnCmdMsg(UINT nID, int nCode, void* pExtra, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO* pHandlerInfo)
//{
//  switch (nID)
//  {
//  case IDC_SELECTED_CLEAR:
//  {
//      if (nCode == CN_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI)
//      {
//          CCmdUI* pCmdUI = (CCmdUI*)pExtra;
//          pCmdUI->Enable( _pSelectedObjects->SelectedCount() > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE);
//          return TRUE;
//      }
//      if (nCode == CN_COMMAND)
//      {
//          _pSelectedObjects->Clear();
//          return TRUE;
//      }
//  }
//  break;
//  }
//
//  return CCmdTarget::OnCmdMsg(nID, nCode, pExtra, pHandlerInfo);
//}


void CGuiBridge::OnSelectedClear()
{
    _pSelectedObjects->Clear();
}


void CGuiBridge::OnUpdateSelectedClear(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->Enable(_pSelectedObjects->SelectedCount() > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE);
}



#ifdef _DEBUG
void CGuiBridge::AssertValid() const
{
    CCmdTarget::AssertValid();
}

#ifndef _WIN32_WCE
void CGuiBridge::Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const
{
    CCmdTarget::Dump(dc);
}
#endif
#endif //_DEBUG
```

Comment: It's not enough to create a `CCmdTarget` derived object, you also need to somehow insert it into MFC's [Command Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shfzay75.aspx) scheme. See [Overriding the Standard Command Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytfexb5k.aspx) for a starting point.

Comment: Thanks - I understand that now, so I have called the instance from the framewnd OnCmdMsg before routing to rest of app.